# Emmet trigger key not working properly in vim

Tags: vim

I have a strange problem whit emmet's trigger key. I have installed it and enable it just for html/css:

```
let g:user_emmet_install_global = 0
autocmd FileType html,css EmmetInstall
```

Then i have redefine emmet's trigger key from `'<C-Y>'` to `'<C-Z>,'`, I have read this from its official mattn/emmet [github](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim) repository.

Then I create index.html, and type

```
html:5
```

and trigger key should generate a html5 page but instead I have this:

```
html:5^Z,
```

Been using emmet for like a mount and a half, and from yesterday trigger key just stoped responding. I have tried to read some SO Answers regarding emmet, but did't solved the problem.
Can any one tell me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: You might be using  `let g:user_emmet_leader_key='<C-Z>,'` but you don't need the comma. Setting it to `'<C-Z>'` maps the trigger key to `<C-Z>,`. This might fix it. It's weird that it just stopped from yesterday, though.

Comment: Have trying that two,  but the problem was in some plugins that I use, I have reconfigureted mine .vimrc and now it runs perfect.